# Как передать значение переменной нескольким файлам php

Tags: php

Надо передать значение переменной переходя по сслыке не только person.php, но и script2.php ?

```
<a href="/person.php?u_link=XXX ...</a>
```

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете что переходя по ссылке `href="/person.php?` - отрабатывает `person.php`, но никак не `script2.php`?

Comment: @Oleg Zolotarenko принимайте гет параметр в файле person.php, а для второго файла script2.php используйте конструкцию включения include.

Comment: согласен. спасибо! я понял логику :)